# Put value to undefined array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm storing values to a not-predefined array because I don't want to calculate the exact size of array.
My code is like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Student_Array = [James, Johns]
dataframe1 = pd.read_csv("D:\\data"+".csv",names=['Name','height', 'weight'])

for ii in range(len(dataframe1)):
    for i in range(len(Student_Array)):
        if int(dataframe1.Name[ii])==int(Student_Array[i]):
            SAVE[i,0]=int(dataframe1.height[ii])
            SAVE[i,1]=int(dataframe1.weight[ii])
```

but it says

> NameError: name 'SAVE' is not defined

The simple solution is generate a np.zeros array, like this, SAVE=np.zeros((500,100))

I really don't want to calculate the size of SAVE array. How to i get a dynamic size(?) array which is automatically re-sized...?

Update:

Now I'm trying this. it works but np.array has 1 dimensions... it dose not have a enter(?).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Student_Array = [James, Johns]
SAVEarr = np.array([])
dataframe1 = pd.read_csv("D:\\data"+".csv",names=['Name','height', 'weight'])

for ii in range(len(dataframe1)):
    for i in range(len(Student_Array)):
        if int(dataframe1.Name[ii])==int(Student_Array[i]):
            SAVEarr = np.append(SAVEarr, np.array([dataframe1.Name[ii],dataframe1.height[ii],dataframe1.weight[ii]]))
```

Comment: What is `SAVE`? It should be a dictionary, as you be using it in your code

Comment: SAVE is not defined.... I thinked it should be a array...but I will define SAVE to a dictionary first in my code.

Comment: Can you provide your complete code for a deeper insight?

Comment: Initialize as `SAVEarr = np.zeros((len(Student_Array), len(dataframe1))` but still, `arr` in the last line is not defined in your code

Comment: Thank you! and sorry, arr in SAVEarr = np.append(arr, np.array([dataframe1.Name[ii],dataframe1.height[ii],dataframe1.weight[ii]])) is SAVEarr. I will edit it.

Comment: Could you please include the expected output for some sample input?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can run it like this:

```
a = dataframe1
saveA = [[a.Name[i],a.height[i], a.weight[i]] for i in range(len(dataframe1))
                                              for ii in range(len(Student_Array))
                                              if dataframe1.Name[i]==Student_Array[ii]]
print(saveA)
```